# Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.beans.MutablePropertyValues.get(Ljava/lang/String;)Ljava/lang/Object

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, soap

I'm creating a SOAP Server with springframwork but I want that my server receive a SOAP request from SOAP 1.2 and I'm trying force it.

I saw in internet that I need use spring-ws-core with the bean:

```
<bean id="messageFactory" class="org.springframework.ws.soap.saaj.SaajSoapMessageFactory">
    <property name="soapVersion">
        <util:constant static-field="org.springframework.ws.soap.SoapVersion.SOAP_12" />
    </property>
</bean>
```

But I think that I have the issue because some incompatibility between spring-ws-core and springframework.

My pom:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>pt.ama.services.ws.server</groupId>
<artifactId>AMAMulticanalWS</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>WebService Maven Webapp</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <!-- Spring -->
    <spring-framework.version>3.2.18.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>3.8.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <!-- <version>6.0.5</version> -->
        <version>5.1.44</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.2.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>       
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.xml.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.8</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Spring and Transactions -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-tx</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-framework.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.ws</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-ws-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.0.0.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>       
</dependencies>
<build>
    <finalName>AMAMulticanalWS</finalName>
</build>
```

Any idea?

Best Regards.

Comment: Spring WS 3.0.0 requires Spring 5.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Web Services 3.0.0. requires Spring 5 as you are using Spring 3.2.18 that doesn't meet that requirement. See [SWS-994](https://jira.spring.io/browse/SWS-994).

Comment: If I tried to use springframework 5.0.1.RELEASE I don't know why I need increase the time of startup the tomcat server and I get this erro:
`Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/exc/InvalidDefinitionException`

Comment: You cannot just upgrade to 5 as you would have to upgrade all your libraries (hibernate 5 is the minimal supported version for instance). Instead downgrade to a supported version of Spring WS.